# EVReflection.setDateFormatter() supporting multiple formats

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, datetime, json-deserialization

I have encountered a problem with deserialization of my DateTime strings from JSON in swift.

I have entity containing multiple NSDate values (which are received from .NET WebAPI server). My problem is that some of JSON properties contain date strings formatted like this: `"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss"` and some have miliseconds contained, like this: `"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSS"`

In entity initializer there is statement selecting my NSDateFormatter (without it none of date strings is getting deserialised):

```
EVReflection.setDateFormatter(NSDateFormatter.isoDateFormatter())
```

and `isoDateFormatter` looks like this:

```
class func isoDateFormatter() -> NSDateFormatter {
    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss"
    formatter.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
    return formatter
}
```

After my entity is mapped into an object, `NSDate` properties containing miliseconds were not mapped to object leaving those properties `nil` while properties without miliseconds are mapped

Example:

```
{
"startTime" : "2018-10-05T10:15:00",    // is deserialized
"startTrackingTime" : "2018-10-05T10:14:59.637"    // is not deserialized
}
```

What I want to accomplish is just to deserialize all date strings into NSDate properties, I even dont need milliseconds part but i don't know how to tell the EVReflection to use more than one NSDateFormatter or more than one date-time format or to just ignore milliseconds part.

EDIT: I can't use NSISO8601DateFormatter because it does not support iOS 9, only iOS 10+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution for this situation I have found is defining custom property converter for properties with different Date format.

This is example of one custom property converter I have used.

```
key: "startTrackingTime",
decodeConverter: {
    let formatter = NSDateFormatter.isoMilisecondsDateFormatter()
    self.startTrackingTime = formatter.dateFromString($0 as! String)
},
encodeConverter: {
    let formatter = NSDateFormatter.isoMilisecondsDateFormatter()
    if self.startTrackingTime != nil {
        return formatter.stringFromDate(self.startTrackingTime!)
    } else {
        return ""
    }
}
```

Where `isoMilisecondsFormatter()` is

```
class func isoMilisecondsDateFormatter() -> NSDateFormatter {
    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.SSS"
    formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
    formatter.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
    return formatter
}
```

So, I had to specify exact formatter for each property that is not received in 
(let's say) "default" format which seems as a really hacky way to do it, but I did not know better.

If someone has better solution I would appreciate sharing it with others.